# Pointing member of struct to struct itself in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Here are two structs I'm using. I'm not sure how to initialize so that member of the struct points to struct itself. I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

```
typedef struct __node 
{
   int value;
   struct __node* left;
   struct __node* right;
}setNode;

typedef struct __set {
   setNode* root;
   //mutex for this set (To be implemented)
}set;
```

I want to initialize members of set but not sure how should I do to get
`result->root` to point to same address as that of `set result`.

```
set* new_set() 
{ 
  set* result = malloc(sizeof(set));
  result -> root = NULL; // Not sure???
}
```

I want to get the pointer to root.

```
void someOther(set* s)
{
   setNode* temp = s -> root;
   //....
}
```

Sorry if the question is too vague.

`Additional Info`

I want two structs. One which is contains nodes of a tree[setNode] and second struct which contains pointer to root of the tree and some other members(like mutex for that tree)[set]. That is not a problem.

Problem: In a function, I have `setNode* temp = someSet -> root;` such that I should be able to traverse over the tree i.e temp should point to root of someSet. So what should I assign to `result -> root` in new_set function?

Comment: `__node` is UB as it contains two consecutive underscores. Don't do that.

Comment: @Bathsheba Not UB, but such names are reserved.

Comment: Question is independent of layout...

Comment: What do you mean that you want `result->root` to point to `result`? That makes no sense. `result->root` is a pointer to `setNode` and not a pointer to `set`. Can you please tell us the *actual* and *original* problem you want to solve, instead of asking us to help you fix a solution to an unknown problem? ([Related reading about the XY problem.](http://xyproblem.info/))

Comment: Oh, I will remove the double underscores. Thanks! @Bathsheba

Comment: Pretty unclear what you want, please elaborate your question. And yes [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) may apply here.

Comment: @DineyWankhede: Hang on!  This was initially tagged "C++" - where double underscore is reserved to the implementation.  You have removed the C++ tag, and it is now only tagged C.  In C, double underscore is perfectly legal.  (OTOH, there is no need to have the struct tag and the typedef name be different - `struct setNode; typedef struct setNode setNode; struct setNode { int value; setNode left; setNode right; };` is fine.

Comment: Here's a binary tree implementation. Why don't you study it until you really understand it. Then you'll be free to code and adapt and solve your problem. https://gist.github.com/ArnonEilat/4611213

Comment: @MartinBonner Nope, double underscore are reserved in C as well (C11 specification §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried to add some information on original problem.

Comment: "So what should I assign to result -> root in new_set function?" - "Pointing member of struct to struct itself in C" - these are two different things. Which one is the question you are actually asking?

Comment: Let's set terminology straight. `setNode` does not "contain nodes of the tree". It **is** a (type of a) **single** node. If you want something that contains **nodes**, you probably need an array of nodes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : Ah-ha!  That is new.  I've just checked my copy of C99+TC1.  `^_[A-Z_]` - reserved for any use.  `^_` reserved for use with file scope. (+ names mentioned in the library are reserved if the header is included).  Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

An empty set doesn't contain any elements. If a set is represented by a binary search tree, a NULL root pointer is appropriate for that.

```
set* new_set() 
{ 
   set* result = malloc(sizeof(set));
   result -> root = NULL; // Yes, absolutely positively 100% sure
   return s; // Don't forget!
}
```

If you want to get the pointer to root, get it.

```
void someOther(set* s)
{
    setNode* temp = s -> root;
    //!!!!
}
```

Nothing whatsoever is wrong with `temp` being NULL. Your function must be able to handle that. If you want a recursive traversal function, write one that gets a `setNode*` argument:

```
void someOther(set* s)
{
    setNode* temp = s -> root;
    someOtherDoThisActuallyIMeanItNow (temp);
}

void someOtherDoThisActuallyIMeanItNow (setNode* current)
{
    ...
    if (current) { // <-- here we check that it's not NULL
       ...
       someOtherDoThisActuallyIMeanItNow (current->left);
       ...
       someOtherDoThisActuallyIMeanItNow (current->right);
    } else {
       // do whatever is appropriate for an empty tree/set
    }
}
```

If you need a function that recursively traverses *and modifies* a tree, make one that accepts a `setNode**` argument.

```
void someOtherWithMutation(set* s)
{
    setNode* temp = s -> root;
    someOtherWithMutationNow (&temp); // <---- here
}

void someOtherWithMutationNow (setNode** current) // <---- here
{
    ...
    if (*current) { // <-- here we check that it's not NULL
       ...
       someOtherDoThisActuallyIMeanItNow ((*current)->left);
       ...
       someOtherDoThisActuallyIMeanItNow ((*current)->right);
       ...
       if (...) {
           free (*current);
           *current = NULL;
       }           
    } else {
       // do whatever is appropriate for an empty tree/set
       ...
       *current = malloc(sizeof(setNode));
       ...          
    }
}
```